# How to update mysql and show div element when finished countdown with this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, css

How to update mysql ,show div element and hide element when finished countdown with this code ?

When finished count i want to hide

```
<button>OK</button>
```

and show

```
<div>time out</div>
```

and update Mysql too

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjdZf/127/)

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
<button>OK</button>
<div>time out</div>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
function countdown(){
    today = new Date();

    BigDay = new Date("2014-09-3 22:39:00");
    msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ;
    timeLeft = (BigDay.getTime() - today.getTime());
    e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
    daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);
    e_hrsLeft = (e_daysLeft - daysLeft)*24;
    hrsLeft = Math.floor(e_hrsLeft);
    minsLeft = Math.floor((e_hrsLeft - hrsLeft)*60);
    secLeft = Math.floor( 60 - today.getSeconds() );
    $('#countdown').html("<ul><li><small>" + daysLeft + "</small><span>Days</span></li><li><small>" + hrsLeft +"</small><span>Hours</span></li><li><small>" + minsLeft + "</small><span>Minutes</span></li><li><small>" + secLeft + "</small><span>Second</span></li></ul>");
}

setInterval(countdown, 1000);
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your code , I do some correction, and you can try it.

http://jsfiddle.net/willHsu/yjdZf/128/intervalId

It's the correct type

```
BigDay = new Date(2014, 07, 03, 15, 02, 00);
```

and If you want to break an interval , you have to add some code, do those things you want to do when 
timeLeft is smaller than 0.

```
function countdown(){
    today = new Date();
    BigDay = new Date(2014, 07, 03, 15, 12, 00);
    msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ;
    timeLeft = (BigDay.getTime() - today.getTime());
    e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
    daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);
    e_hrsLeft = (e_daysLeft - daysLeft)*24;
    hrsLeft = Math.floor(e_hrsLeft);
    minsLeft = Math.floor((e_hrsLeft - hrsLeft)*60);
    secLeft = Math.floor( 60 - today.getSeconds() );
    $('#countdown').html("<ul><li><small>" + daysLeft + "</small><span>Days</span></li><li><small>" + hrsLeft +"</small><span>Hours</span></li><li><small>" + minsLeft + "</small><span>Minutes</span></li><li><small>" + secLeft + "</small><span>Second</span></li></ul>");
    if(timeLeft < 0 ){
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
        /* do something*/
        $('#button1').hide();
        $('#countdown').hide();
        $('#div1').show();
    }

}
var refreshIntervalId =  setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

Hope it will help you!